# what does it mean by array $options = [] in method argument

Tags: php, class, arguments

I found a php class in the internet that uses array $options = [] in method argument:

```
class TADFactory
{
    private $options;


    public function __construct(array $options = [])
    {
        $this->options  = $options;
    }

//some other methods here
}
```

and in page.php file

```
$tad_factory = new TADFactory(['ip'=>'192.168.0.1']);
//some other stuffs here
```

But after executing the page.php file in the browser, it is showing:

```
Unexpected `[` in page.php file at line 1, expecting `)`....
```

But according to the php library documentation, I have to use the multidimensional array in argument by that way.

I could not understand what does it mean by `array $options = []` in TADFactory class argument and why the error is throwing?

Comment: What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: `array` is a type-hint forcing you to pass an array, `= []` sets `$options` to an empty array if nothing is passed (default).

Comment: That short array syntax was introduced in PHP 5.4. If you're running an older version, you'll need to change it to use `array $options = array()` and `$tad_factory = new TADFactory(array('ip'=>'192.168.0.1'));`.

Comment: If that's the case, you'll have to change `TADFactory(['ip'=>'192.168.0.1']);` to use the old syntax as well, and probably quite a few other usages of the "new" array syntax.

Answer (score 0):

That is a [default argument value](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php). It is how you declare that a parameter is optional, and, if not provided, what value it should have by default.

```
function add($x, $y = 5) {
    return $x + $y;
}

echo add(5, 10); // 15
echo add(7); // 12
```

As for the array annotation, that is a [type hint](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration) (also called a type declaration), which means that you must pass the function an array or it will throw an error. Type hinting is fairly complicated and debatably necessary in a dynamic language, but it's probably worth knowing about.

```
function sum(array $nums) {
    return array_sum($nums);
}

echo sum([1, 2, 3]); // 6
echo sum(5); // throws an error
```

NOTE: You can only combine type hints with default argument values if your default argument value is null.